# Getting "The application environment is not set correctly." in Laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I had a working Laravel 7.x (7.28.3) project and then ran *php artisan config:clear* and am now getting "The application environment is not set correctly." on every page, any ideas?   I had also modified a vendor file to test something but reverted which could also be the cause.  Everything I can google shows CodeIgniter errors but I am using Laravel....

Comment: I can't even find the string "is not set correctly" in a Laravel project, including all of vendor

Comment: how are you setting environmental variables?

Comment: Is there a `.env` file in the project root?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was server related and fixed with restart.